# line 15: Syntax error: Variables of array type are not supported

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I keep getting the error: line 15: Syntax error: Variables of array type are not supported!
not sure what is wrong exactly can anyone help? see code below

```
//@version=4
// Constants
study("Example Trading Indicator v6", overlay=true)
stopLoss = 50 // Stop loss distance in points
takeProfit = stopLoss * 3 // Take profit distance in points

// Indicators
rsiValue = rsi(close, 14)
smaValue = sma(close, 50)
macdValue = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdSignal = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdHist = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

// Buy or Sell Conditions
buy = (rsiValue > 70) and (smaValue > close) and (macdHist > 0)
sell = (rsiValue < 30) and (smaValue < close) and (macdHist < 0)

// Plotting
bgcolor(buy ? color.green : sell ? color.red : na)

stopLossBuy = low - stopLoss
stopLossSell = high + stopLoss
takeProfitBuy = low + takeProfit
takeProfitSell = high - takeProfit

plot(buy ? stopLossBuy : na, title="Stop Loss (Buy)", color=color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(buy ? takeProfitBuy : na, title="Take Profit (Buy)", color=color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(sell ? stopLossSell : na, title="Stop Loss (Sell)", color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(sell ? takeProfitSell : na, title="Take Profit (Sell)", color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)

plot(buy ? 1 : 0, title="Buy", color=color.green, style=plot.style_circle, linewidth=3)
plot(sell ? -1 : 0, title="Sell", color=color.red, style=plot.style_circle, linewidth=3)

plot(rsiValue, title="RSI", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
plot(smaValue, title="SMA", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(macdValue, title="MACD", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

trying to plot stop loss and take profit area based on the buy or sell criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign tuple to a variable, or a variable to a tuple. So to solve this issues you can convert to list, then make all of your changes, and convert again to tuple at the end.

Read this [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_change_tuple_item.asp)

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you. I will do some more reading on Pinescript

Answer (score 0):

The `macd()` function return a tuple of three MACD series: MACD line, signal line and histogram line, so you'll need to write the code like this:

```
[macdValue, macdSignal, macdHist]  = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
```

You also have minor issue with the `plot` `style` argument (it need to be `style=plot.style_circles` not `style=plot.style_circle`.

Working code:

```
//@version=4
// Constants
study("Example Trading Indicator v6", overlay=true)
stopLoss = 50 // Stop loss distance in points
takeProfit = stopLoss * 3 // Take profit distance in points

// Indicators
rsiValue = rsi(close, 14)
smaValue = sma(close, 50)
[macdValue, macdSignal, macdHist]  = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

// Buy or Sell Conditions
buy = (rsiValue > 70) and (smaValue > close) and (macdHist > 0)
sell = (rsiValue < 30) and (smaValue < close) and (macdHist < 0)

// Plotting
bgcolor(buy ? color.green : sell ? color.red : na)

stopLossBuy = low - stopLoss
stopLossSell = high + stopLoss
takeProfitBuy = low + takeProfit
takeProfitSell = high - takeProfit

plot(buy ? stopLossBuy : na, title="Stop Loss (Buy)", color=color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(buy ? takeProfitBuy : na, title="Take Profit (Buy)", color=color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(sell ? stopLossSell : na, title="Stop Loss (Sell)", color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
plot(sell ? takeProfitSell : na, title="Take Profit (Sell)", color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)

plot(buy ? 1 : 0, title="Buy", color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
plot(sell ? -1 : 0, title="Sell", color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)

plot(rsiValue, title="RSI", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
plot(smaValue, title="SMA", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(macdValue, title="MACD", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```